# Android Studio 3.2.1 Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alphal]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to android studio constantly running into problems with it (Mostly after any update). This issue came up right after I did the "IDE and plugin update". Now none of my projects build.

Here's the error

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments
[com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alphal] on object of type
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

When I go into the SDK manager it shows the Android Support Repository ticked (as to say it's present)

Here's my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.namey.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alphal'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'   // Added for slide-in menu
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'         // Added for slide-in menu design
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.1'    // For transitions
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Even after re-downloading the android support repository i still get the same error

Comment: as the error says, 
`Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.` go to sdk manager -> sdk tools -> support repository and install it.

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alphal, What is this alpha"l"

Comment: @Mrinmoy sorry it's alpha1 not "l" a mistake while transferring the code from android studio here

Answer (score 0):

What's your version of Gradle ? (in the root build.gradle). Because this version needs to be at least 3.4 for `implementation` to work. (Sorry, am not yet able to comment).

Comment: My gradle version is 4.6... Everything was working fine until yesterday.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning cache and restart : **File-clean and restart** ?

Comment: Yes I tried that too. I've deleted the repository and I'm re-downloading it (what I've been trying to avoid). I'll see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You should use the version `28.0.0` instead of it's `28.0.0-alpha1`, which if it's following convention, should be an older, buggier version.
Otherwise, just download it with the SDK Manager in Android Studio.